# Flexbox как убрать перенос блока на новую стороку

Tags: html, css, flexbox

[image: Сетку, которую необходимо получить]
Есть `flexbox` сетка

```css
.news_items {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.news_item {
  width: 33%;
}

.news_item:first-child {
  width: 50%;
}

.news_item:nth-child(2) {
  width: 50%;
  height: 230px;
}

.news_item:nth-child(3) {
  width: 50%;
  height: 230px;
  align-self: flex-start;
}

.news_item>img {
  width: 388px;
  height: 231px;
}

.news_item:first-child>img {
  width: 588px;
  height: 469px;
}

.news_item:nth-child(2)>img {
  width: 585px;
  height: 230px;
}

.news_item:nth-child(3)>img {
  width: 585px;
  height: 230px;
}
```

```html
<section class="news">
  <h2>Новости</h2>
  <div class="news_items">
    <div class="news_item">
      <img src="img/work1.png">
    </div>
    <div class="news_item">
      <img src="img/work1.png">
    </div>
    <div class="news_item">
      <img src="img/work1.png">
    </div>
    <div class="news_item">
      <img src="img/work1.png">
    </div>
    <div class="news_item">
      <img src="img/work1.png">
    </div>
    <div class="news_item">
      <img src="img/work1.png">
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Хотел узнать, почему блок `nth-child(3)` переносится на строку под `first-child`, а не под `nth-child(2)`? И как сделать, чтобы блок оставался под `nth-child(2)`?

Answer (score 0):

flex-wrap: wrap;
разрешает перенос на новую строку
вообще немного странный код у вас. 
дочерние элементы в сумме составляют больше 100%.

```css
.news_items {
  display: flex;
  
}
```

```html
<section class="news">
  <h2>Новости</h2>
  <div class="news_items">
    <div class="news_item">
      <img src="img/work1.png">
    </div>
    <div class="news_item">
      <img src="img/work1.png">
    </div>
    <div class="news_item">
      <img src="img/work1.png">
    </div>
    <div class="news_item">
      <img src="img/work1.png">
    </div>
    <div class="news_item">
      <img src="img/work1.png">
    </div>
    <div class="news_item">
      <img src="img/work1.png">
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Добавил скриншот структуры, которую необходимо получить, поэтому больше 100%